# Is this an action of $S_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}_{n}$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

I am trying to prove that $S_{n}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}_{n}$ with the map $$* : S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{n}, \quad * \left( \sigma, \left( r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n} \right) \right) = \left( r_{\sigma_{\left( 1 \right)}} ^{-1}, r_{\sigma_{\left( 2 \right)}} ^{-1}, \dots, r_{\sigma_{\left( n \right)}} ^{-1} \right).$$

However, I realized the map is undefined for any $n$-tuple having one or more coordinates equal to zero, so I suspect it is not an action. Am I right? If so, what would be the correct map?

---

**UPDATE 1:** After working this out I think, even if the map is defined as $$* : S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{n}, \quad * \left( \sigma, \left( r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n} \right) \right) = \left( r_{\sigma_{\left( 1 \right)} ^{-1}}, r_{\sigma_{\left( 2 \right)} ^{-1}}, \dots, r_{\sigma_{\left( n \right)} ^{-1}} \right),$$

that **it is not** an action of $S_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}_{n},$ and the reason for this is precisely the identity $\left( \sigma_{1} \circ \sigma_{2} \right)^{-1} = \sigma_{2} ^{-1} \circ \sigma_{1} ^{-1},$ for $\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2} \in S_{n}.$ Here's what I did:

\begin{align}
* \left( \sigma_{1} \circ \sigma_{2}, \left( x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} \right) \right) & =  \left( x_{\left( \sigma_{1} \circ \sigma_{2} \right)^{-1} \left( 1 \right)}, \dots, x_{\left( \sigma_{1} \circ \sigma_{2} \right)^{-1} \left( n \right)} \right) \\ & = \left( x_{\left( \sigma_{2} ^{-1} \circ \sigma_{1} ^{-1} \right) \left( 1 \right)}, \dots, x_{\left( \sigma_{2} ^{-1} \circ \sigma_{1} ^{-1} \right) \left( n \right)} \right) \quad \text{(This is the key step)} \\ & = \left( x_{\sigma_{2} ^{-1} \left( \sigma_{1} ^{-1} \left( 1 \right) \right)}, \dots, x_{\sigma_{2} ^{-1} \left( \sigma_{1} ^{-1} \left( n \right) \right)} \right) \\ & = * \left( \sigma_{2}, \left( x_{\sigma_{1} ^{-1} \left( 1 \right)}, \dots, x_{\sigma_{1} ^{-1} \left( 1 \right)} \right) \right) \\ & =  * \left( \sigma_{2}, * \left( \sigma_{1}, \left( x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} \right) \right) \right),
\end{align}

but we would like to have $* \left( \sigma_{1} \circ \sigma_{2}, \left( x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} \right) \right) = * \left( \sigma_{1}, * \left( \sigma_{2}, \left( x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} \right) \right) \right)$ instead.

Is this correct?

---

**UPDATE 2:** I am really confused now. Looking in the web I found two different notes on group actions. In one, they say the map defined as $$\phi : S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{n}, \quad \phi \left( \sigma, \left( r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n} \right) \right) = \left( r_{\sigma_{\left( 1 \right)}}, r_{\sigma_{\left( 2 \right)}}, \dots, r_{\sigma_{\left( n \right)}} \right)$$

**is not** a group action, while in the other one they say it is. I think, by my own calculations, that $\phi$ is a group action, but I'm not sure now.

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: It seems you misunderstand how the product $\sigma x$ is being defined. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and write its coordinates $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$. Then you permutate the coordinates of $x$ by the of $\sigma^{-1}$. I think you meant to write $r_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}$ instead of $r^{-1}_{\sigma(j)}$.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki I think you are right, I think wrote the exercise incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki yes, I deleted my comment just after posting it.

Comment: @CarlRojas The map is an action. You need to show that $\sigma(\sigma' x) = (\sigma\sigma')x$. This comes down to knowing that $(\sigma\circ \sigma')^{-1} = \sigma'^{-1}\circ \sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Just one question: If the map is defined as you say, then it would be trivial stuff, since $\sigma^{-1} \left( i \right) = i,$ right? It would be basically $* \left( \sigma, \left( r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n} \right) \right) = \left( r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n} \right).$

Comment: @Carl Yes it is trivial to show that the identity fixes every element in $\mathbb{R}^n$.